# Accidental SQL Injection Triggered from SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-injection

Weird way to put this, but couldn't think of a better way to title this.

I know to an extent, using LINQ/Entity/SqlParam/etc helps with the protection against SQL Injections.  My customer is asking if there is **any liability exposure from allowing a midlevel DBA person who is running SQL queries from Management Studio** to accidentally run malicious code which is already stored as a value in the DB.

I wouldn't think it would be an issue, but then I thought about some more advanced queries where you have loops, etc. where it may read the value of an email field which may have a value such as:

```
--Let's say this value already is stored in the database
--since Linq/Entities/SqlParams prevented it from running in code
--but it obviously still stored it inside of the field.
x'; DROP TABLE members; --
```

...and then perhaps do something with it which could cause it to execute.  Thought I better ask around for some opinions before giving an answer on this.

Comment: It might be possible to inject a poorly written stored procedure, but it would depend on the particular code.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.  I just hate giving that answer of, "Well anything is possible.".  In this case I guess I could attach, "Is it likely....probably not...but a badly executed SP could cause that to happen..."

Comment: The thing is, if that attack happens, it's an attack from the inside, from someone in whom management has a high degree of trust.  On the other hand, a SQL injection coming from the outside, e.g. via a malicious AJAX request, is a different thing.  In that case, we never trustsd this person in the first place.

Comment: This is not "anything is possible", this is a real possibility for a poorly written SP. However, the real question is: Why the midlevel DBA would need to even bother with figuring out how to run malicious code? They can simply run the malicious query directly in the Management Studio. So what's the point here? You want to give somebody the keys to your house, but you don't trust them and you're scared they will break in through the window and steal something? :)

Comment: LOL Racil....However, I think maybe I described this the wrong way perhaps.  What I meant was, the value is inside of the email field already in the database.  (this is the code I shared above).  So the question is, Entity/SqlParams on the server side obviously didn't concatenate the SQL, so it wouldn't run the malicious value...however is it possible for this code to execute and accidentally be run when doing queries on the backend via a DBA.  I hope that clears it up a bit.   I don't believe it would be possible, but I always like to ask around.

Comment: I've also edited my original post to help clarify the question a bit.

Comment: I see, so it's not about trusting the DBA, but rather the data entries in the database. Again, yes that's a real possibility, but that's not the fault of the DBA running the SP, it's the fault of whoever wrote the SP. When writing SPs, you need to think about SQL injection similar to when you write queries in the app's code. You should never concatenate string parameters to inline SQL and just execute it, you must sanitize them first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing stored procedures, you must think about SQL injection similar to when you write queries in the application's code. You should never concatenate string parameters to inline SQL and just execute it, you must sanitize them first.

In fact, inline queries are bad and should be avoid it whenever possible, whether in the application's code or in stored procedures. However, sometimes we do need them in stored procedures, in which case you must sanitize any parameters or database values before you concatenate them to the inline query. If you don't do that properly, then there will be a real risk of SQL injection with those stored procedures.

Comment: Sanitize parameters is almost always a bad thing. Use parametrized queries instead, and consider "sanitization" only as a last resort for queries that don't accept parameters (DDL for example).

Comment: @Alejandro I totally agree, but if you read my answer carefully, I was talking about an inline string query inside a stored procedure. Sadly, you cannot use a parameterized query there instead. That's why I said to avoid it whenever possible (which is similar to your saying "as a last resort"), but I need to use an inline string query in your stored procedure, you will have to sanitize your parameters and database values used in the query, there's no way around that.

Comment: There is the system stored procedure `sp_executesql` which takes a dynamic SQL string plus its parameters, thus making dynamic SQL fully parametrizable, exactly the same as submiting commands from the client. A plain `EXEC @sql` is almost always wrong. That would cover the vast majority of cases, leaving sanitization as a last resort.

Comment: @Alejandro Yes, again totally agree. That's much better than using `EXEC @sql`, but the question was not tagged with SQL Server when I answered and my answer was general for any database. I'm not sure that every database has similar way to use parameterized queries, but the ones that have such an option, we should always favour it over dynamic SQL.

Comment: Really great discussion and I've tagged Racil's answer as the accepted answer since he and Tim B. had some great comments in the question area as well.  I think the real takeaway here for me is that more attention to potential SQL injection inside of stored procedures, which honestly I never really thought about until this question.  Thanks to everyone for responding!